# wait until the end of an action before starting the other

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I start the action with a slight gap between them?

```
    $('.html').css( 'width', '98%' );
    $('.html').text( "98%" );
    $('.css').css( 'width', '98%' );
    $('.css').text( "98%" );
```

I tried it with `.delay()` but does not work.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: how about `settimeout`?

Comment: `delay()` would work if you put 'actions' into queue

Comment: You "*tried it with .delay()*" but did you read the docs for `delay()` by any chance?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below. Change `200` for more or less delay.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.html').css( 'width', '98%' );
    $('.html').text( "98%" );
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('.css').css( 'width', '98%' );
        $('.css').text( "98%" );
    }, 200);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will force each function to execute after it's previous one has stoped

```
$('.html').css( 'width', '98%' )
.queue(function() {
   $('.html').text( "98%" )
   .queue(function() {
        $('.css').css( 'width', '98%' )
        .queue(function() {
            $('.css').text( "98%" );
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
        $(this).dequeue();
   });
   $(this).dequeue();
})
```